# Динамический ссылки не работает в чем проблема?

Tags: javascript

Динамический ссылки не работает в чем проблема? `Old Link` работает, а `New Link` нет.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
[].forEach.call(a, function(o, i) {
  a[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e.target.text);
  };
});
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = function(e) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '#';
  a.innerHTML = 'New Link';
  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(a);
};
```

```css
button {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eef;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Add</button>
<div>
  <a href="#">Old Link</a>
  <a href="#">Old Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы изначально присвоили всем старым ссылкам событие и когда добавляете новый элемент, у него нет события нажатия, так как вы ему его не присвоили.
Каждый раз, когда вы добавляете элемент, нужно заново присваивать ему событие

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');

var click = function(e) {
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
  alert(e.target.text);
};

[].forEach.call(a, function(o, i) {
  a[i].onclick = click;
});

var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = function(e) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '#';
  a.innerHTML = 'New Link';

  a.onclick = click;

  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(a);
};
```

```css
button {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eef;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Add</button>
<div>
  <a href="#">Old Link</a>
  <a href="#">Old Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант - можно ловить событие на уровне контейнера вместо уровня единичной ссылки:

```js
var links = document.getElementById('links')
links.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // Поиск нажатой ссылки - это не нужно в данном примере, но нужно в общем случае, когда внутри ссылки могут быть дочерние элементы
    var target = e.target;
    while (target !== this && target.tagName != "A")
        target = target.parentElement;
    
    if (target.tagName == "A") {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert(target.text);
    }
})

var add = document.getElementById('add')
add.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#';
    a.innerHTML = 'New Link';
    links.appendChild(a);
});
```

```html
<button id=add>Add</button>
<div id=links>
  <a href="#">Old Link</a>
  <a href="#">Old Link</a>
</div>
```